# Restricted values for `getBlockPrefix` in symfony 4

Tags: forms, symfony, symfony4

I'm building a simple CRUD using symfony 4.
One of my entities is called `Color`. Nothing fancy about it. It just has 4 properties: name, description, sortOrder and id (PK).
I also built a form class to be able to add/edit my entity instances. 
The form looks like this:

```
<?php
namespace App\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\IntegerType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\HiddenType;

class Color extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('id', HiddenType::class)
            ->add('name', TextType::class)
            ->add('description', TextareaType::class, ['required' => false])
            ->add('sort_order', IntegerType::class);
    }
}
```

When I try to render the form I get an error

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class App\Entity\Color could not be converted to string").

I have other forms that look similar and they work.

If I don't let symfony decide the block prefix  based on the class name and add the method

```
public function getBlockPrefix()
{
    return 'anything-else-but-color';
}
```

then the form is rendered.
I don't want to do that because my app is kind of "convention" based and I need a match between the entity class name and the form name.
I know I can change both the entity and the form class names (and I'm probably going to do that) but this bugs me because I don't know what happens and if there are any other reserved words that might screw up my app.

Additional info...
I can partially debug this.
I see that when the form is rendered something like this is generated

```
<input type="color" id="color" name="color" class="form-control" ....
```

(notice the type color).
For a different entity and form built in the same way (named `group`) I get this rendered in the same place as above.

```
<div id="group">...
```

So my questions are:

1. **Are there any reserved words that cannot be used for `getBlockPrefix` in a form?**
2. **Can I use the word `color` as a block prefix without jumping through many hoops?**

Comment: When you have a 'could not be converted to string' error it's usually solved by adding a __tostring() function to the entity, which would probably return name, or description.

Comment: @AlisterBulman Added that. That's how I was able to debug it partially and saw that an `<input type="color"` is rendered in the page. That's not a desired behavior.

Comment: So to be clear - if you take your entity and form and rename it to something else it works, ie it is specifically the name "Color" it is falling over?

Comment: @Bananaapple. Yep. This is exactly what happens. Renamed it to `Colour` or `AchievementColor` and it worked. But the name `color` does not work. I think it may have something to do with the fact that there is  a form field type called `ColorType` (`Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ColorType`) but cannot quite debug it. If this is the case, I will settle for an explanation like 'because there is a color form input type, this happens ... <insert explanation here>'.

Comment: @Bananaapple Also, only changing what `getBlockPrefix` returns will make it work, but this is not an option for me as it would screw up my conventions.

Comment: The documentation for https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/create_custom_field_type.html touches on this: "
When the name of your form class matches any of the built-in field types, your form might not be rendered correctly" but I would have expected this to trigger if your form type was called `ColorType`

Comment: Hmmm...you might be on to something. I think it crashes for me because the `Type` at the end of the class name is ignored.  `StringUtil::fqcnToBlockPrefix('Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ColorType');` and `StringUtil::fqcnToBlockPrefix('Whatever\YouWant\Color');` return the same thing:  `color`. You should write your finding as an answer. Just for the record, I've been on the page you linked but totally missed that section.

Comment: @Marius if this can be consistently reproduced in s4 it may be worth to file a bug report to either have the behaviour or the documentation updated...

Comment: not sure about this. Since it is documented this looks more like a limitation than a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/create_custom_field_type.html) touches on this:

> When the name of your form class matches any of the built-in field
>   types, your form might not be rendered correctly. A form type named
>   `App\Form\PasswordType` will have the same block name as the built-in
>   `PasswordType` and won't be rendered correctly. Override the
>   `getBlockPrefix()` method to return a unique block prefix (e.g.
>   `app_password`) to avoid collisions.

I would have expected this to trigger if your form type was called `ColorType` however, for completeness sake as per your comment:

> I think it crashes for me because the Type at the end of the class
>   name is ignored.
>   `StringUtil::fqcnToBlockPrefix('Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ColorType');`
>   and `StringUtil::fqcnToBlockPrefix('Whatever\YouWant\Color');` return
>   the same thing: `color`